# YUI 3 TabView Issue

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, yui

I would like to create two tabs in a Jsp page using YUI 3 (Yahoo UI3).

For Example:
Tab1 Tab2

Tab1:
I am able to create Tab1 using the below java script.

```
createCustomTabSafari = function(lblTxt,eId){

YUI().use('tabview', function(Y) {
    var tabview = new Y.TabView({
        children: [{
            label: lblTxt,
            content: document.getElementById(eId)
        }]
    });       
     tabview.render('#demo');
     tabview.selectChild(0);
  });
}
```

Now I want to add Tab2 with some static text like label: 'Tab2', content: 'test'. I have tried with createCustomTabSafari ('Tab2','test') but it is created a tab at some other location instead of creating besides the Tab1.

How to use addChilld()/add() method to add the second tab as a child instead of a brand new tab.

I have gone through the YUI API and could see addChild(child, index) method but not sure how to use this method in this scena`enter code here`rio.

Also, How to read the tabs that are created that is if I know tab1 is clicked I will display something and if Tab2 is clicked I will display something different.

It would be helpful if I get to know something on adding a second tab next to the Tab1.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The examples on the YUI website do a really good job of showing how to use the Tabview. You can see this example which has multiple tabs: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/tabview-fromjs.html

```
YUI().use('tabview', function(Y) {
    var tabview = new Y.TabView({
        children: [{
            label: 'foo',
            content: '<p>foo content</p>'
        }, {
            label: 'bar',
            content: '<p>bar content</p>'
        }, {
            label: 'baz',
            content: '<p>baz content</p>'
        }]
    });

    tabview.render('#demo');
    tabview.selectChild(2);
});
```

And for adding and removing tabs, a rather complex example: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/tabview-add-remove.html

Comment: The examples show creating static Tabs. I would like to create tabs dynamically. First I want to create Tab1 dynamically because based on some data/check Tab1 can be displayed multiple times but Tab2 should be displayed only once.

Comment: If you follow through the detailed example in the second link you'll see that it uses the `add()` method. http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/TabView.html#method_add